# Viscosity equations for rockets

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, water, rocket-science, viscosity

I'm doing an experiment about the effect of viscosity on water rockets, and was wondering if there are any equations that include viscosity that are significant to rockets/water rockets.

Comment: IMHO, instead of wondering you would have searched on internet on this topic and include your work here and directly ask the conceptual doubts.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of parameters that affect viscosity, specially in low velocity flows like those on water rockets. I think you should check out this page from NASA, it's a good start to those who want to learn about rocket physics and they make some references to viscosity and its effects, so it may be helpful for you.

This is the main index on the compressible aerodynamics section, you should take a look since there are some interesting things:

https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/shortc.html

Directly related to fluid dynamics and viscosity check the Reynolds number and the viscosity pages:

https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/viscosity.html

https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/reynolds.html